Experience with modern ROS2 support/reliability on RHEL?
I am looking at building a system with ROS2 Jazzy within my company at the moment. We Originally planned to use Ubuntu but after chatting with IT it seems that RHEL is the officially supported Linux distro for our business and I am being pushed towards using that instead.
Does anyone have any experience using RHEL with ROS2? How is it compared to Ubuntu? I understand that in the past the packages were only supplied as source code for RHEL but that has since changed. Are there any other differences?
